# Error with mex file ... ....Index exceeds matrix dimensions. Index value 3 exceeds valid range [1-2] of array gesgroup

Tags: matlab, mex, matlab-coder

I have a function file to mex file. But it is giving error when running the mex file. Following is the code.

In the code I have initialised 3 vectors named group,horgroup,gesgroup and declared gesgroup as varsize.

```
group = zeros(1,2);    
horgroup = zeros(1,2); 
gesgroup = zeros(1,2); 
coder.varsize('gesgroup');
```

in few lines group and horgroup are calculated as arrays of size (1 * 2) say group = [1 2] and horgroup = [3 4] later i need to merge group and horgroup into gesgroup using

```
gesgroup = [group, horgroup];
gesgroup(gesgroup==0) = NaN;
```

this code is not giving any error while generating a mex file but when I am running the mex file its giving error in above two lines, saying "Index exceeds matrix dimensions. Index value 3 exceeds valid range [1-2] of array gesgroup"

Let me know if I need to change anything in the code and generate the mex file again.

Comment: *I have a function file to mex file* - what does that mean? From reading your question I'm not even sure where the call to the mex function is, or how it is related at all. You're unlikely to get an indexing error from a mex function, unless your C code checks for that and throws an error, or you return a vector/matrix from the mex function that is smaller than in should be, in which case it'd be MATLAB throwing the error, and not the mex function. You should be able to debug this further by setting `dbstop if error` and running your code, then inspecting the dimensions and indices.

Comment: @Praetorian I am guessing it is a MATLAB function m-file compiled directly to mex using matlab-coder (generally done for speed increase), and then used within MATLAB, if so I can see the issue...

Comment: @Praetorian -- that what it means what RTL said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in initialisation `gesgroup` is initialised with size 1x2 but the line

```
gesgroup = [group, horgroup];
```

will make it 1x4 ( as both group and horgroup are 1x2), you need to initialise it as such ***or*** as variable size
e.g.

```
gesgroup = zeros(1,4);
```

*or*

```
coder.varsize('gesgroup')
```

I think the problem has occurred as the size is determined before `coder.varsize('gesgroup')` is reached, so the array is already fixed size

Comment: I would check declaring coder.varsize('gesgroup') before gesgroup = zeros(1,2) and would let you know

Comment: Does it even need to be variable size? if its first defined as `[group, horgroup]` and remains 1x4 surely it is simpler to just have it initalised as 1x4?

Comment: it worked perfectly.  Size of gesgroup is not always (1 * 4), it depends on the size and type of input